# What is the difference between drivers and libraries in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am wondering what is the difference between drivers and libraries in the embedded C programming. Assuming that I am using uControllers that only have application code/firmware like PICs

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208572/in-embedded-is-there-any-difference-between-a-device-driver-and-a-library

Comment: I clearly understood what the driver's role is, but I am not sure about the libraries and why their implementation modules are not accessible for the user. Thank you.

Comment: A "driver" is a collection of one or more routines that serve the specific purpose of providing an interface to particular hardware.  A "library" is just a collection of routines, not necessarily related, serving any purpose.  Each term can be applied in various contexts, including source code; compiled, unlinked code; and executable programs.  Especially in the last of those, a driver and/or library might not be distinguishable as an independent object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With respect to deeply embedded systems (such as the PIC) the distinction is generally that a driver is tied to the hardware and is not portable between platforms, while a regular library should be portable and have no direct hardware dependencies. This is not a hard and fast rule, however it is the most consistent one that I have come across in embedded systems.

It is also common for vendors to call a collection of drivers a library so in a way you can think of drivers as just a special type of hardware dependent library, and a library as simply a collection of related code.